# How to highlight selected rows in table grid when searchtext matching using jquery?

Tags: css, jquery

Displaying row values in table grid. whenever user seraching particular record then i need to check that text matching with any of the rows.if matched the record need to change the background color of the row.if not matched need to display the original color of the grid rows.

please check my code how to display the original color if records are if records are not matched.?

```
$(function () {
        grid = $('#userGrid');

        // handle search fields key up event
        $('#search-term').keyup(function (e) {
            text = $(this).val(); // grab search term

            if (text.length > 1) {
               // grid.find('tr:has(td)').hide(); // hide data rows, leave header row showing

                // iterate through all grid rows
                grid.find('tr').each(function (i) {
                    // check to see if search term matches Name column
                    if ($(this).find('td:first-child').text().toUpperCase().match(text.toUpperCase()))
                        $(this).css({ background: "#FC6" }); 
                      //  $(this).show(); // show matching row
                });
            }
            else
                grid.find('tr').show(); // if no matching name is found, show all rows
        });
    });
```

Design :

```
<label for="search-term">Search by Name</label>
<input type="text" id="search-term" />
    <table id="userGrid">
    <th>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
    </th>
    <tr>
        <td>John Smith</td>
        <td>john.smith@johnsmith.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sally Sue</td>
        <td>sally.sue@sallysue.com</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add this line to your code : see **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Cf76G/)**

```
grid.find('tr').each(function (i) {
   $(this).css({ background: "#FFF" });//  <= this line
   // check to see if search term matches Name column
   if ($(this).find('td:first-child').text().toUpperCase().match(text.toUpperCase()))
           $(this).css({ background: "#FC6" }); 
        //  $(this).show(); // show matching row
 });
```

Comment: if search text is null need to show original grid .no need of showing previous highlight row record.

Comment: you are welcome, so you can add again this line to `else` block, means `if(text.length==0)`

Comment: grid.find('tr:has(td)').css({ background: "" });

Comment: How to check for all columns.above only working for first column ?can you please tell me how to apply for all columns ?

Comment: if suppose 3 columns are there in a table grid i need to check all those in above checking with names(first column ) only.